# Preserve special character $ during XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

I currently faced on xsl transformation trouble.
I have XML file (install.xml) with available property (it is a password).
Into this xml, the value of the property is correctly set with this value : "test-V$you"

```
<xslt in="/tmp/entry.xml" out="../test.ini" style="../test.xsl">
<param name="Password" expression="${Password}"/>
</xslt>
```

When I pass this property as a param with xslt transformation, the value is not well preserved : "test-V"

```
<xsl:param name="Password"/>
echo "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Password : <xsl:value-of select="$Password"/>"
```

How to preserve in XSL file the $ character ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the Ant property named "Password"?

My guess is that you set it something like this:

```
<property name="Password" value="test-V$you"/>
```

I'm no expert on the intricacies of Ant but $ is a special character and I would try escaping the "$" as "$$".

If that's not how you set the Password property, then please tell us how you did.

This page might confuse you as much as it confused me...

http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html

Comment: You're right about the setting of the variable. It is setting in other XML file which i'm importing. However i dont want to manage the escaping into the XML file because for other requirement regression. The aime is to manage the escaping or any xsl funtions if exists into the xsl file test.xsl directly. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No sorry I don't know the answer I was just trying to point you in the right direction.